# Irreducibility of a polynomial, Hartshorne chapter 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 4.2 of chapter 1, it says implicitly that if $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is irreducible then $x_{n+1}f-1$ is also irreducible but it doesnt say why. Can you give me a hint please? I'm really stuck.

Comment: It has degree $1$ as a polynomial over $x_{n+1}$. You don't need $f$ irreducible.

Comment: My problem is that he considers a "hypersurface" $H=Z(x_{n+1}f-1)$. His definition of hypersurface is that of a algebraic variety generated by a irreducible polynomial in more than 2 variables. That's why I need to show that $x_{n+1}f-1$ is irreducible as a polynomial in all $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ variables.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963933/on-a-hartshornes-statement)